# Return vector from function

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have two classes, the first that contains a vector and a get-method like this:

```
std::vector<mytype> const& MyClassA::getvector(std::vector<mytype>::iterator &it)
{
    it = this->myiterator;

    return this->myvector;
}

std::vector<mytype> myvector;
std::vector<mytype>::iterator myiterator;
```

and I have another class where I should use the vector:

```
MyClassB::myfunction()
{
    std::vector<mytype>::iterator it;
    std::vector<mytype> vector = MyClassA->getvector(it);

    if (it > vector.begin())
    {
        ....
        (--it)->dosomestuff();
        ....
    }
}
```

in the if I get a runtime exception: iterators incompatible. Why?

**EDIT 1**

```
void MyClassA::setvector(mytype myelement)
{
    this->myvector.push_back(myelement);
    this->myiterator = this->myvector.end() - 1;
}
```

Comment: Where are you initializing myiterator?

Comment: @Rocky added one more function to the answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have made a copy of the vector in the calling code, and the iterator isn't valid because it's still pointing to the original vector.

You probably intended something like this:

```
const std::vector<mytype> & vector = MyClassA->getvector(it);
```

Comment: @Mark it works but I have still a problem, I should move the iterator in the MyClassB function and save the current position in the original variable stored in class MyClassA

Comment: @Stefano Switch the parameter and the result. Store a copy in the parameter and return the new iterator. `newvec.begin()+(olditer-oldvec.begin())` should work.

Comment: @Let I need to get a vector as return from the function. It all works now but it doesn't save in the original iterator variable the new value, MyFunctionB is working on an iterator copy

Comment: @Stefano Well, then take int as a parametr and store the distance there.

Comment: @Let, good solution, anyway just for curiosity why isn't the function passing the original iterator rather than a copy?

Comment: @Stefano that's not the issue, the iterator is pointing inside the original vector, not your local copy, that's the problem

Comment: @Let wait wait, it's correct. That iterator should point always to the original vector because I need to move it up and down in the vector... I don't need to work on a local copy of the iterator, neither on a local copy of the vector

Comment: @Stefano But you have a copy of the vector :-D

Comment: @Let so it's not correct :( I want to use the original vector (i don't need to edit the elements inside it, only use them) and I need to save in the original iterator variable the new position

Comment: @Stefano, you want both the vector and the iterator to be references? If so then you need to break your function in two, since a reference must be assigned when it is declared and can't be changed later. Let one function return a reference to the vector and the other return a reference to the iterator. Although I must say this is a very dangerous way to code.

Comment: @Mark I want to access the elements inside the vector (I don't need to edit them, only read-only operations) and I need to move the iterator up and down outside of the MyClassA class. To move the iterator I need to have the original variable, not a local copy and this is what it's happening, the function returns a copy

Answer (score 1):

Since you return `std::vector<mytype> _const_&`, the type of its iterator is `std::vector::const_iterator`.

*EDIT:*

Ah yes, I'm wrong and **Mark Ransom** is right. I leave this answer here because of the discussion in the comments, which itself may be useful to someone else.

Comment: @sehe You can't get an iterator out of constant vector, but this is totally irrelevant in this case.

Comment: @sehe: @vines is correct, from a `const vector&`, only `const` member functions will be called, which return `const_iterator` (not `const iterator`).

Comment: @Ben But he doesn't have a const vector.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: He has a `const vector&`, the return type of `getvector()`.

Comment: @Ben: that's irrelevant; the code compares an `iterator` to a `const_iterator`, which is valid (or would be if they came from the same vector). The problem has nothing to do with what is `const` and what isn't.

Comment: @Mike: agreed that this isn't the problem.  But @sehe's comment was wrong (more so before edit) and I wanted to respond to it.

Comment: All: I'm sorry I misread the statement (I thought I read 'returning `const std::vector<mytype>::iterator`' when obviously, that wasn't written). Can we delete all these spammy comments?